# How to find mysql log in xampp?

Tags: 16.04, mysql, xampp, logs

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, Xampp 7.2 64 bit, how to find MySQL logs? I tried all the answers listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638128/where-can-i-find-the-mysql-log-file-in-xampp), none worked, not the error logs, mysql logs so I can connect it to Logstash.

Comment: Isn't there a `logs` directory in the Xampp folder?

Comment: @muru Yes but it contains only 4 files `access_log`, `error_log`, `php_error_log` and `ssl_request_log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked on [Xampp forum](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=77688) and was just told:

> Xampp does not activate MySQL logging. [See here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html) how to enable
>   logs.